# How do I write an if/else statement inside a function that tells me if a number is evenly divisible by 2 (in javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm working through codacademy and I can't understand the help discussions in the forum.

This is what I have so far but it returns false when i run the function with an even number:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
 if (isEven % 2 == 0){
  return true;
 }else{
  return false;
 }
};
```

Comment: replace `isEven` with `number` inside the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are performing the mathematical operation on `isEven` (the function itself). You need to check `number`:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    if (number % 2 === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

or better yet:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    return number % 2 === 0;
};
```

You could even do this, by making use of the truthy/falsy behavior of `1` and `0`:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    return !(number % 2);
};
```

but I think the previous approach more clearly conveys how the logic works.

Answer (score 1):

you can write this function as follows:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
 return ((number % 2) == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not working because you're checking against the function name, not the function parameter (number). Try this:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    return number % 2 == 0;
}
```

Comment: you made the same mistake ;) you should use `return number ...`

Answer (score 1):

You doing it wrong in `isEven` itself..
Do it like..

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    return number% 2 == 0;
}
```

Comment: please note that you should compare the passed parameter instead of the function itself inside the method

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

- `0` is considered to be `false` in Javascript.
- `1` is considered to be `true` in Javascript.
- `!` makes `false` become `true` and vice versa.
- The `%` operator can be used to keep higher numbers in a zero-to-one range.

Since `0 % 2` gives `0` (i.e. `false`) and `1 % 2` gives `1` (i.e. `true`), you simply need to invert the result with `!`:

```
function isEven(x) { return !(x % 2); }

console.log(isEven(0));  // true
console.log(isEven(1));  // false
console.log(isEven(2));  // true
console.log(isEven(3));  // false
```

Note that this could also be written as:

```
function isEven(x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }
```

...because:

- `0 % 2` is `0` (so it is `true` to say that it is equal to zero).
- `1 % 2` is `1` (so it is `false` to say that it is equal to zero).

Comment: nice one thanks, simple and readable. it's just a little bit confusing, that you have to use the exclamation mark

Comment: You really don't, you can compare to 0. `x % 2 === 0`

Comment: I've updated my answer to include this option, along with an explanation about why it causes the same result as the first version.